# TeX Live 2021, memoir, chemmacros and float conflict

Tags: floats, memoir, chemmacros, texlive-2021, bugtracking

I recently updated all TeX Live 2021 packages to their newest versions and after that documents that use `memoir`, `chemmacros` and `float` no longer work.

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    some text
\end{document}
```

Compiling this document fails with the following error: `LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

So far I have discovered the following:

- The problem did not occur before updating to newest package versions.
- The problem does not occur if I switch documentclass to `article`.
- The problem does not occur if I remove either `chemmacros` or `float`.
- The problem still occurs if I change the order of `chemmacros` and `float`.
- I tried this with two computers one of which is running Linux and another that has Windows installed and the same thing happens with both.
- I also tried typing the file entirely from scratch to make sure that there are no invisible characters that could cause the problem.

My question is what should I do with this problem? This looks like a bug, but I don't know which package has the bug, so I don't know where I should submit the bug report.

Is there anything that I can do to make this work?

What steps should I take in order to troubleshoot this problem and figure out what is causing it?

Here is the full output.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2021/06/16 v3.7p configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem10.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/delarray.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)
LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/before/framed' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/framed/before' instead.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/before/float' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/float/before' instead.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemmacros/chemmacros.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))
Loading the chemmacros module `base' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
Loading the chemmacros module `errorcheck' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `lang' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)))
Loading the chemmacros module `greek' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemgreek/chemgreek.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))
Loading the chemmacros module `chemformula' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `charges' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `acid-base' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `symbols' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `particles' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `phases' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `nomenclature' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `tikz' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecoration
s.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
Loading the chemmacros module `isotopes' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elements/elements.sty)
Loading the chemmacros module `mechanisms' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `newman' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `orbital' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `polymers' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `reactions' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)))
Loading the chemmacros module `redox' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty)
Loading the chemmacros module `xfrac' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xfrac/xfrac.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.st
y))
Loading the chemmacros module `scheme' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemnum/chemnum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psfrag/psfrag.sty))
Loading the chemmacros module `spectroscopy' ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty)
Loading the chemmacros module `thermodynamics' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `units' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `reactants' ...
Loading the chemmacros module `translations' ...
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemformula/chemformula.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/nicefrac.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.
meta.code.tex))
./document.tex:6: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
l.6 \begin{document}
?
./document.tex:6: Emergency stop.
 ...
l.6 \begin{document}
./document.tex:6:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on build/document.log.
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: probably a problem of chemmacros, it does lots of patches. Make a bug report.

Comment: `\c@[=\count383`  interesting latex counter name,  `[`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `memoir` does `\AtBeginPackage{float}{\let\newfloat\relax}` which effectivly undefines `\newfloat`. Now, when `float` is loaded the `\newfloat` definition of `float` is valid and not the one of `memoir`. `chemmacros` however still thinks that the definition of `memoir` is valid.

`memoir`'s version of `\newfloat` has an optional argument, `float`'s version doesn't. So when `chemmacros` does this at begin document

```
\newfloat[chapter]{scheme}{los}{scheme}
```

it now is equivalent to

```
\newfloat{[}{c}{h}apter]{scheme}{los}{scheme}
```

A float named `[` is defined and `apter]{scheme}{los}{scheme}` is typeset which triggers the error.

The whole thing could probably be regarded as bug of `chemmacros`. Prior to version 6 `chemmacros` this didn't come to light because `chemmacros` didn't load the `scheme` module per default. Now it does.

So until I fix this you can load a minimal `chemmacros` and only add the modules you need (without the `scheme` module)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[minimal,modules={redox,reactions}]{chemmacros}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

#### Update

This is fixed in `chemmacros` v6.1 (2022/02/13)